# Sending an automated text message with python to multiple numbers

Tags: python, automation, twilio, sms

I'm trying to create a script that will send automated text messages to my clients reminding them about payment being due. I found the code below and it works for sending text to my number, but I can only send the text to my number and not to other unverified numbers.

I believe to get the other numbers verified I need to upgrade my account, is there an alternative I could use? If I have to pay I have to pay, but I wanted to see if there were other options

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'AC.....'

auth_token = 'c58....'

twilio_phone_number = '18339####'

to_phone_number = ['17########']

message_body = "Hello, this is a test message from user using Python! I'm just practicing"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create( body=message_body, from_=twilio_phone_number, to=to_phone_number, )

print(f"Message sent with SID: {message.sid}")
```